# GUI appearance in remote desktop

Tags: graphics, gui, remote-desktop

Suddenly, all the applications with GUI on the remote desktop of my server started looking like this: [Paraview graphics interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ekc.jpg), totally unusable.

Can someone please point me to the right setting for restoring right proportions? Server OS is Ubuntu 16.04 and I am accessing it via X2GO client.

Thanks in advance,
Jacopo

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: If you're actually using 16.04, I hoped you switched your apps to *snap* package as you'll note if you read the ESM security notes for 16.04, that a number of desktop apps were only supported via *snap* package with ESM. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/ESM/16.04 etc

Comment: Maybe you need to change the resolution in the X2GO client?